# Google Colab Text Wrapping Assistance

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-publisher-tag

I am new to coding and would greatly appreciate your guys' help. I'd like to be able to wrap this text, but I am unsure as to how.

```
gpt2.generate(sess,
      length=500,
      temperature=1.01,
      prefix="Mutko went on to add that '",
      nsamples=10,
      batch_size=10,
```

Comment: Could you be more specific of what are you willing to obtain?

Comment: I really enjoy the ability to generate text, but I have a visual issues that troubles me when reading the text. If I was able to wrap the text into paragraph like form, I'd me much easier on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using pprint or textwrap.

Comment: Please consider explaining how to use either ```pprint``` or ```textwrap``` in the context of the original post.